# Change type of currency on 3 prices

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I collect the price of the coins from a JSON with `fetch`, I hope it is well done.

I want when I give any currency the base price it has, that I pick it up from the innerHTml and put it in a const. My problem is that when I do the first select, the current currency is fine and makes the conversion great, but when I change again, the current currency is worth 1 instead of 2 as it is in the first `<h1>`. and subtracts until it is 0

Another problem that I can't get is that it is applied to the 3 `<h1>`

```js
//cambio de moneda
function getCurrency() {
   fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/eur.json')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => {
      crearMoneda(data);
   })
}

getCurrency();


function crearMoneda(moneda) {
   const eur = moneda.eur.eur;
   const usd = moneda.eur.usd;
   const gbp = moneda.eur.gbp;

const selectCoin = document.getElementById('coin');
const priceCoin = document.querySelector('.priceCoin');
selectCoin.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
   
      let coinSelected =  event.target.value;
      const currentCoin = parseInt(priceCoin.innerHTML);
      console.log('currentCoin', currentCoin)
      let result;
      switch (coinSelected) {
         case 'eur':
            console.log('euro selected', eur)
            result = currentCoin * eur;
            priceCoin.innerHTML = result;
            break;
         case 'usd':
            console.log('usd selected', usd)
            result = currentCoin * usd;
            priceCoin.innerHTML = result;
            break;
         case 'gbp':
            console.log('gbp selected', gbp)
            result = currentCoin * usd;
            priceCoin.innerHTML = result;
            break;
      }
   
})

}
```

```html
 <select name="coin" id="coin">
                <option default>Select coin</option>
                <option value="eur">EUR</option>
                <option value="usd">USD</option>
                <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
            </select>

<h1 class='priceCoin'>2</h1>
<h1 class='priceCoin'>25</h1>
<h1 class='priceCoin'>60</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the change doesn't get applied to all the h1 tags is because when you use querySelector(".priceCoin") it only returns the first tag with the priceCoin class, in order to get all the 3 tags you should use querySelectorAll which wil return all the h1 tags in the form of an array.
You also need to store the initial values in an array so that everytime a new currecny is selected, you convert the same initial values to the selected currency and not the result from the previous conversion.
Then you only need to loop through the initial values using a forEach loop and multiply each value by the selected currency and display the result inside the correspunding tag.(I've created an object for the currency values so that it'll be easier to access each value by just passing the key of the needed currency.)

```js
//cambio de moneda
function getCurrency() {
  fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/eur.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      crearMoneda(data);
    })
}

getCurrency();


function crearMoneda(moneda) {
  const eur = moneda.eur.eur;
  const usd = moneda.eur.usd;
  const gbp = moneda.eur.gbp;

  const selectCoin = document.getElementById('coin');
  const priceCoinsArr = document.querySelectorAll('.priceCoin');

  const initalVals = [2, 25, 60]
  const exchangeValues = {
    "default": 1,
    'eur': eur,
    'usd': usd,
    "gbp": gbp
  }
  selectCoin.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let coinSelected = event.target.value;

    initalVals.forEach((value, index) =>
      priceCoinsArr[index].innerHTML = value * exchangeValues[coinSelected]
    )
  })

}
```

```html
<select name="coin" id="coin">
  <option value="default" default>Select coin</option>
  <option value="eur">EUR</option>
  <option value="usd">USD</option>
  <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
</select>

<h1 class='priceCoin'>2</h1>
<h1 class='priceCoin'>25</h1>
<h1 class='priceCoin'>60</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now im understand how to use filter better and the use of objects to simple. This works perfect. I want to know if my fetch its well done

Comment: np :) your fetch request works fine, although you can add a catch block just in case an error occurs during the fetch process, like this :
`fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/eur.json')
    .then(res =>
      res.ok ?
      res.json() : 
       res.text().then(text=>{throw(new Error(text))})
     )
    .then(data => {
      crearMoneda(data);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err.message));`
also you can simply just destructure the needed values from the  moneda.eur object like this: `const {eur, usd, gbp} = moneda.eur`